# Two independent function when considered as random variable over $([0,1],\mathrm{Lebesgue},\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]})$

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Does there exists two non-constant continuous functions $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that they are in independent (in probability sense) when viewed as random variables over the measure space $([0,1],\mathrm{Lebesgue},\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]})$, where $\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]}$ is the Borel sigma field of $[0,1]$?

I was trying the following thing. Let $U(x)=x$ be be a function on $[0,1]$. This follows uniform distribution. Now I am taking binary exapnsion of $U$. It can be proved that 
$$U = \sum_{k\geq 1}B_k/2^k,$$
where $B_k$'s are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$. In particular $$B_k(x)=\mathbb{1}(k^{\text{th}}\;\text{binary digit of $x$ after decimal point is 1}).$$ Here $\mathbb{1}(\cdot)$ is the indicator function. Now I am defining
$$f=\sum_{k\;\text{is odd}}B_k/2^k,\quad g=\sum_{k\;\text{is even}}B_k/2^k.$$ 
Thus $f$ and $g$ are independent but I can not prove they are continuous, though they are almost surely continuous w.r.t lebesgue measure. Any help will be appreciated. Please provide any other example if available. Thank you.

Comment: They are not continuous, for example $f$ jumps at $x=1/2$ (it's also not completely clear if you even defined $f$ at $x=1/2$, but of course that's the smaller problem).

Comment: Also, you probably want to add the requirement that $f,g$ are not constant a.e.

Comment: @ChristianRemling You are right. Constant functions should not be allowed here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can take a Peano curve $\varphi: [0,1]\to [0,1]^2$. More precisely, we want a construction like the one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#Outline_of_the_construction_of_a_space-filling_curve) that spends its fair share of the time in each dyadic square when traced out at unit speed. This will make sure that the image measure of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ under $\varphi$ is (two-dimensional) Lebesgue measure again.

Of course, on the square we have random variables as desired (the coordinates), and we can now pull back to $[0,1]$ and take $f(x)=\varphi_1(x)$, $g(x)=\varphi_2(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The binary digits $\epsilon_1(x),\epsilon_2(x),\ldots$ of a number $x$  in $[0,1]$ are independent under Lebesgue measure, so the two random variables defined by
$$
f(x) := \sum_{k=1}^\infty {\epsilon_{2k}(x)\over 2^k}
$$
and
$$
g(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\epsilon_{2k-1}(x)\over 2^k}
$$
are independent, and they are evidently continuous functions of $x$. Both are uniformly distributed.

Comment: The function $f$ is *not* continuous. Consider the sequence $(x_n)$ where $x _1 = 0.01, x_2= 0.011, x_3 = 0.0111, \ldots$, and so on, in binary. This converges to $0.0111.... = 0.1$. But $f(0.1) = 0$, while $f(x_n)$ converges to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 1$.

Comment: A successful implementation of your strategy would amount to the same as Christian Remling's answer - defining a space-filling curve $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^2$ whose projections are independent random variables. Though it may not be apparent from versions that are drawn using diagrams, Peano's original paper describes his curve using (ternary) digits.